# Programmatically configure Log4j2 to replace each logfile when the size is above 1MB

Tags: java, log4j2

Hello I have a problem with log4j2. I want to configure it programmatically like described in this post: Configure log4j2 programmatically using ConfigurationFactory My problem is with the size of the log file. I want the system to start a new logfile, if the logfile size is over 1 MB. Here is my code i call the static configure() method in main. It is working but the sizeBased policy does not work. The logfile grows and grows. I do not want to use any xml.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Order;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;

public class LoggingConfiguration {

    public static final String PATTERN_LAYOUT = "[%d] [%t] [%-5level] - %msg (%logger{1}:%L) %n%throwable";
    public static final String LOG_FILE_NAME = "gvg.log";
    public static final String LOG_FILE_NAME_PATTERN = LOG_FILE_NAME + "-%d{dd-MM-yyy}";

    static {
        ConfigurationFactory.setConfigurationFactory(new Log4j2ConfigurationFactory());
    }

    public static void configure() {
    }

    @Plugin(category = "ConfigurationFactory", name = "Log4j2ConfigurationFactory")
    @Order(0)
    public static class Log4j2ConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

        @Override
        protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Configuration getConfiguration(ConfigurationSource source) {
          return new Log4j2Configuration();
        }

        @Override
        public Configuration getConfiguration(String name, URI configLocation) {
          return new Log4j2Configuration();
        }

    }

    private static class Log4j2Configuration extends DefaultConfiguration {

        private static final String PATH_LOGFILE = "c:\\temp\\";

        public Log4j2Configuration() {
            setName("gvg-log");
            String root = PATH_LOGFILE;
            Layout<? extends Serializable> layout = PatternLayout.createLayout(PATTERN_LAYOUT, null, null, null, false, false, null, null);

            String oneDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1) + "";
            String oneMB = (1024 * 1024) + "";
            final TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy timeBasedTriggeringPolicy = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(oneDay, "true");
            final SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(oneMB);
            final CompositeTriggeringPolicy policy = CompositeTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(timeBasedTriggeringPolicy, sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy);
            final DefaultRolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.createStrategy("7", "1", null, Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION + "", this);
            Appender appender = RollingFileAppender.createAppender(root + LOG_FILE_NAME, LOG_FILE_NAME_PATTERN, "true", "gvg-log-file-appender", null, null, null, policy, strategy, layout, null,
            null, null, null, null);
            addAppender(appender);
            getRootLogger().addAppender(appender, Level.ALL, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use XML config? IMHO it's much more convenient to configure Log4j with XML file. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Comment: Boss doesn't want xml

Comment: I don't know Log4j2 API but example given in this question seems to work just fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886717/configure-log4j2-programmatically-using-configurationfactory

Comment: No it doesn't roll the logfile.

Comment: the last parameter to 'RollingFileAppender.createAppender' is your configuration. Try passing your configuration(this reference) and not null and see it if helps.

Comment: Thanks but it did it it didn't help.

Comment: What OS is it? Is the file being accessed by some other process simultaneously?