# Better way to initialize log4j2 (TWO) programmatically

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

This is what I'm doing to load the log4j2.xml file, specifying the log file location from another property file to keep configuration simple for support purposes:

```
MyProperties props = MyProperties.getInstance();
System.setProperty(MyConstants.AUDIT_LOG_ENV_VAR,
        props.getAuditLogFileName());
ConfigurationSource source =
        new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream(new File(
                System.getProperty(MyConstants.PROPERTIES_FILE_ENV_VAR)
                    + "/log4j2.xml")));
Configurator.initialize(null, source);
```

and log4j2 will pick up and use my file name because I've specified it in the Appender using envvar substitution:

```
<File name="AuditLogger" fileName="${sys:AUDIT_LOG}">
  <PatternLayout pattern="DATETIME  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz}%n%msg%n" />
</File>
```

However I don't like it because there's a smell about pushing the file name value out to the system environment before reading it back in again on the next line of code.

I like [Configure log4j2 programmatically using ConfigurationFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886717/configure-log4j2-programmatically-using-configurationfactory) but there doesn't seem to be a similar way to build more on top of a log4j2.xml file - or is there?

Comment: Don't you use Java 7+?

Comment: I didn't follow your intention. If you don't want to set the property programmatically, would setting it as a jvm argument do?

Comment: @AndyDufresne what exactly are you asking? I would struggle to phrase my question any more unambiguously. The last 2 paragraphs are key.

Answer (score 5):

Generally the log4j2 team does not recommend programmatic configuration: the separation between the api and core jars is to give developers a clear separation between API and implementation. Programmatic configuration relies on implementation details so may break in a future release.

If there's anything that cannot be done with configuration please let us know so we can improve this.

For your particular use case: it looks like you want to set a system property to a certain value *before* log4j2 initializes itself based on that value. If this is a standalone app, one way to avoid depending on log4j2 implementation details is to set all necessary system properties before referencing any log4j2 classes:

```
public class MainWrapper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("key", "value");
        // ... 
        ActualMain.main(args); // delegate to the actual start of the application
    }
}
```

An alternative I would like to draw your attention to is creating your own custom lookup. This can be accomplished in a few lines of code with a log4j2 [plugin](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html). This also relies on some implementation details, but the result is more powerful and reusable.

```
package com.mycompany;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.AbstractLookup;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup;

/** Looks up keys in MyProperties singleton. */
@Plugin(name = "MyProperties", category = StrLookup.CATEGORY)
public class MyPropertiesLookup extends AbstractLookup {
    @Override public String lookup(final LogEvent event, final String key) {
        return MyProperties.getInstance().getValue(key);
    }
}
```

Then, in your configuration you can use your custom lookup instead of system properties:

```
<File name="AuditLogger" fileName="${MyProperties:AUDIT_LOG}">
  <PatternLayout pattern="DATETIME  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz}%n%msg%n" />
</File>
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer about plugins - but that is only the half of it. I am also using `MyProperties` to fetch the log4j2.xml location, which is not on the classpath. You advise against using the log4j2 implementation - how would you do it?

Comment: I would specify the full path of the configuration file with this system property: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`

Comment: I figured you might say that. But then I am back to the same situation as earlier - pushing a variable out to the environment to read it back in again one line of code later. This time it's the log4j2.xml file location instead of the appender's log file. Is there a plugin technique to tell log4j2 where to grab the log4j2.xml?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. Log4j is aware of this system property and will find the configuration file if you specify this property. Then there is no need to read it back in: log4j will automatically do the configuration/initialization. (So you no longer need the custom code in the question.) See also the FAQ: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location

Comment: Yes, I understood that - what I mean is that I have to set the `log4j.configurationFile` in code after getting the value from `MyProperties` and then log4j reads it back in on the next line (approx.)

Comment: you said "If there's anything that cannot be done with configuration please let us know so we can improve this" - I'd suggest a plugin which I can use to tell log4j where the log4j2.xml file is :) (the link you give only offers an implementation specific way)

Comment: Where does `MyProperties` get its values from? I'm trying to understand why you need to get the log4j2 config location from `MyProperties` instead of from a system property...

Comment: It's a requirement to reduce the number of configuration steps required at the OS level. I am already specifying the location of the config file directory on the file system in one envvar, and that is where the `log4j2.xml` file is. It would be an easy win to use that same envvar to tell log4j where its config is, making the configuration process one step shorter: e.g. a plugin that gets the dir name from `MyProperties` and appends `/log4j2.xml` on the end, and passes it to log4j. I use `commons-configuration` to read the properties file at `/etc/myapp/myapp.conf`